# grid-auto-rows .vs min-height. What is the difference?

Tags: css, css-grid

What is the difference between these two codes? What is the advantage of using `grid-auto-rows` while we can simply achieve the same result using a more simple rule such as `min-height`? I personaly cannot find a major difference!

In the first one, I used `grid-auto-rows` to control the height of rows.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px , auto);
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

In the following code, I used `min-height` of the children in order to achieve the same result.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: bisque;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

I know that from the developer's point of view, the first one might be better because the user of this theme do not need to apply class "item" to all the children elements. However, I am curious to know if there is any differences in the final output.

Comment: Are you asking which is better or what is the difference…? Which is better may get closed as opinion-based

Comment: @cocomac Thank you for your warning. I updated my question to be more clear about what I'm asking about

Comment: if you have element inside your container without the class `item` then there is a big difference. It should be noted that with CSS there is always different ways to achieve the same output

Comment: `grid-auto-rows` allows for like 4x as many values (and different value types) compared to `min-height`. This is covered fairly exhaustively in the spec and in help sites like MDN.